# Replace a camel case string with a hyphenated string

Tags: c#

How would I change the string

> aboutUs

To

> about-us

I'd like to be able to do this with regex replace if possible.
I've tried:

```
public static string ToHypenCase(this string source) {
    return Regex.Replace(source, @"[A-Z]", "-$1");
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of regex and `ToLower()`, like this:

```
string s = "quickBrownFoxJumpsOverTheLazyDog";
string res = Regex.Replace(s, @"([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1-$2").ToLower();
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/DReGHH)

Comment: `@"([a-z])([A-Z])"` didn't work for "UsingAnAWord" and "SomeDigit4Used2".  Suggest treating digits like lowercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

If you need fast solution with low allocation (it handles also @PeterL cases):

```
public static string ConvertFromCamelCaseToDashSyntax(string text)
{
    var buffer = ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Rent(text.Length + 10); // define max size of the internal buffer, 10 = max 10 segments

    try
    {      
        var resultLength = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(text[i]) && i > 0)
            {
                buffer[resultLength++] = '-';  
            }
            buffer[resultLength++] = char.ToLowerInvariant(text[i]);
        }

        return new string(buffer.AsSpan().Slice(0, resultLength));

    }
    finally
    {
        ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Return(buffer);
    }
}
```

Benchmark:

| Method | Text | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UsingRegex | quick(...)zyDog [32] | 1,894.7 ns | 2.38 ns | 2.11 ns | 1.00 | 0.0114 | 208 B |
| UsingArrayPoolAndSpans | quick(...)zyDog [32] | 106.3 ns | 0.23 ns | 0.20 ns | 0.06 | 0.0062 | 104 B |

Answer (score 1):

My version using a StringBuilder...

```
    public static string UrlConvert(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return s;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var ch in s.ToCharArray())
            if (char.IsUpper(ch))
            {
                if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append("-");
                sb.Append(char.ToLower(ch));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(ch);
            }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

And xUnit tests...

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("same", "same")]
    [InlineData("Simple", "simple")]
    [InlineData("MultiWord", "multi-word")]
    [InlineData("UsingAnAWord", "using-an-a-word")]
    [InlineData("SomeDigit4Used2", "some-digit4-used2")]
    public void UrlConvertWorks(string input, string expected)
    {
        Assert.Equal(expected, Meta.UrlConvert(input));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your extension method like this:

```
public static string ToHypenCase(this string source)
{
    var chars = source.ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Count -1; i++)
    {
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[i]) && char.IsUpper(chars[i + 1]))
        {
            chars[i + 1] = char.ToLower(chars[i + 1]);
            chars.Insert(i+1,'-');
        }
    }

    return new string(chars.ToArray());
}
```

Or just use `LINQ`:

```
var parts = "aboutUs".Select(x =>
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(x)) return "-" + char.ToLower(x);
            return x.ToString();
        });

var result = string.Join("", parts);
```